# Error creating a query invalid parameter number

Tags: php, sql, pdo

The following script throws me this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Error comes from these lines:

```
$query .= "WHERE username1=:un1";
$binValues["un1"] = $_POST['username1'];
```

Is there any problem with php syntax?

My full script:

```
<?php

    require_once "config.inc.php";  

    $query = "UPDATE customer SET ";
    $binValues = [];


    if(!empty($_POST['eidosmetaf1'])) {
        $query .= "eidosmetaf1 = :e1";
        $binValues["e1"] = $_POST['eidosmetaf1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['weight1'])) {  
        $query .= ",weight1 = :w1";
        $binValues["w1"] = $_POST['weight1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['startNomos1'])){ 
        $query .= ",startNomos1 = :sn1";
        $binValues["sn1"] = $_POST['startNomos1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['startPoli1'])) { 
        $query .= ",startPoli1 = :sc1";
        $binValues["sc1"] = $_POST['startPoli1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['start_lat'])) { 
        $query .= ",start_lat = :slat1";
        $binValues["slat1"] = $_POST['start_lat'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['start_lng'])) { 
        $query .= ",start_lng = :slng1";
        $binValues["slng1"] = $_POST['start_lng'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['finalNomos1'])) { 
        $query .= ",finalNomos1 = :fn1";
        $binValues["fn1"] = $_POST['finalNomos1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['finalPoli1'])) {  
        $query .= ",finalPoli1 = :fc1";
        $binValues["fc1"] = $_POST['finalPoli1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['final_lat'])) {  
        $query .= ",final_lat = :flat1";
        $binValues["flat1"] = $_POST['final_lat'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['final_lng'])) {  
        $query .= ",final_lng = :flng1";
        $binValues["flng1"] = $_POST['final_lng'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['depDate1'])) {  
        $query .= ",depDate1 = :dD1";
        $binValues["dD1"] = $_POST['depDate1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['depTime1'])) { 
        $query .= ",depTime1 = :dT1";
        $binValues["dT1"] = $_POST['depTime1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['specialservices1'])) {  
        $query .= ",specialservices1 = :ex1";
        $binValues["ex1"] = $_POST['specialservices1'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['comments1'])) {  
        $query .= ",comments1 = :c1";
        $binValues["c1"] = $_POST['comments1'];
        }   

        //error here
        $query .= "WHERE username1=:un1";
        $binValues["un1"] = $_POST['username1'];    


        $query .= "and comments1=:c1_old";
        $binValues["c1_old"] = $_POST['comments2_old'];


    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($binValues);

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        die(json_encode($response));
    }    

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "..............!";
    echo json_encode($response); 


?>
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29354264/3933332 don't you think?!

Comment: *Hm...* you might need a space before the `where` --- `$query .= " WHERE username1=:un1";`

Comment: Hello again Rizier, are you always online; hahaha. But i insist: what is now the problem at the specific lines;

Comment: Plus, make sure your `$_POST['username1']` is set and named in your form.

Comment: Did you see comment # deux? `$query .= " WHERE username1=:un1";`

Comment: i saw it and its not working

Comment: You also need a space here `$query .= " and comments1=:c1_old";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I fixed already your previous code I would recommend you to use the code from my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29354781/3933332 because it's a lot simpler to read and understand.

And if you use my code you can add your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
<?php

    //...

    foreach($checkedValues as $k => $v) {
        $query .= "$v = :$k,"; 
        $bindValues[$k] = $_POST[$v];
    }

    $query = rtrim($query, ",");

    //fixed code here
    if(isset($_POST['username1'])) {
        $query .= " WHERE username1=:un1";
        $bindValues["un1"] = $_POST["username1"];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['comments1'])) {
        $query .= " AND comments1=:c1_old";
        $bindValues["c1_old"] = $_POST["comments1"];
    }


    try {           
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($binValues);         
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        die(json_encode($response));
    }    

    //...

?>
```

Comment: @johnnal Then go back to my last answer and see my updated code :D And then you also can combine it with the new code here.

Comment: ok i will. But question remains: why is the specific code i provided wrong;

Comment: @johnnal 2 things. 1. You need to check if the variable is set 2. And the main problem you need to add spaces before you concatenate both strings to the query otherwise you will get something like this: `:c1WHERE username1=:un1AND...` And it won't see where the WHERE and AND clause are

Answer (score -1):

```
$binValues[":un1"] = $_POST['username1']
```

Comment: Adding : doesn't work. Note that statements for example "$binValues["dD1"] = $_POST['depDate1'];" are working perfect